# generate cloud endpoint client library updating the paths

Tags: google-app-engine, path, cloud, endpoint

I have an android connected eclipse project everything was working fine with my old endpoints.

But I have restructured my packages and when I run the "generate cloud endpoint client library script" it generates the old endpoints and ignores my new named endpoints.

How can I update the generate cloud endpoint client library script to use the new java classes?

Is there a command I can use to manually generate the library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command (run from project root):

> $SDK/endpoints.sh get-client-lib com.test.MyEndpoint

If you're on Windows use the following (make sure the AppEngine SDK bin folder is included in your %PATH%):

> endpoints get-client-lib com.test.MyEndpoint

You can also use Maven:

> mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool